# AS build error: Execution failed for task ':MyGeneralLibrary:processDebugResources'. > Error: ' ' is not a valid resource name character

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I have the following error with no indication which resource file is the culprit

> Execution failed for task ':MyGeneralLibrary:processDebugResources'.
>
> Error: ' ' is not a valid resource name character

I have tried running the build with --stacktrace but doesn't tell me which resource file is the issue.

Is there a way I can find where the problem is?

Edit:

MyGeneralLibrary build file:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
    
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    
    dependencies {
        implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4'
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.6.2'
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.6.2'
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:11.6.2' 
        implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.0.2'//this also complains see below
        implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.2'
        implementation 'com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.0.2'
        implementation 'com.android.support:support-fragment:27.0.2'
    }

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
}
```

My project build file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots" }
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

configurations {
    implementation.exclude group: 'com.google.guava'
    implementation.exclude module: 'guava:19.0-rc2'

    all*.exclude group: 'commons-logging', module: 'commons-logging'

    androidTestCompile.exclude group: 'com.google.code.findbugs'
    androidTestCompile.exclude module: 'jsr305:2.0.1'
}

dependencies {
    //project
    implementation project(':MyGeneralLibrary')
    implementation fileTree(dir: '../libs', include: '*.jar')

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.6.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.6.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:11.6.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.6.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:11.6.2'
    implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5'

    implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.0.2'
    implementation 'org.twitter4j:twitter4j-core:4.0.2'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.10.0'
    implementation 'com.github.scribejava:scribejava-apis:2.2.2'
    implementation('com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:1.12.1@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    implementation 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 27
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode 1
        versionName "0.1"
        applicationId "com.chdryra.android.reviewer"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            res.srcDirs = ['src/main/res', 'src/androidTest/res']
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "2g"
    }
}
```

AS complaint: I think it is unrelated, but I have a red line under one of the lines in the MyGeneralLibrary gradle file about recyclerview that cardview and support-media-compat have different versions. dependning on which build file I sync first I sometimes get this error instead:

```
Error:java.lang.RuntimeException: Android dependency 'com.android.support:cardview-v7' has different version for the compile (23.4.0) and runtime (27.0.2) classpath. You should manually set the same version via DependencyResolution
```

Everything was working fine before my update to AS 3.0 so am at a loss about what is going on. Any pointers appreciated!

Thanks,
Riz

Comment: can you share your build.gradle file?

Comment: Thanks Gautam - added!